# Visual Studio 2019 Illegal characters in path

Tags: windows, visual-studio, environment-variables, visual-studio-2019

Lately, I am having a persistent error message. The error message emerges in two conditions at least:

1. After creating a new project (in c# or vb) in .NET Framework, when I right-click -> add... -> new item... the error message shows up.
   [image: .NET Framework]

[image: Add item]

[image: error message]

2- When I try to create a project (c# or vb) in .NET Core I get the same error message directly:
[image: NET Core]

[image: error]

Even if I opened an old project, which works or worked fine, after that, when I try to add a new item I get the same error message.
I have already reported this issue to Microsoft. But still no clear solution. Did anyone get the same problem?
By the way, I have already tried many known tactics like clearing the cache in C:\Users\Salam\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_8c60507b
And I tried to repair or uninstall then reinstall the product. All those tactics didn't help.

[image: environment_variables]

This is the full path of one of my old project, which already has a class. But right now I can not add a new class to it. Since it generates the same error message. The path I copied by right-clicking in VS on the project then choosing 'copy full path'.
D:\Users\Salam\source\repos\test_windowsFormsApp2\test_windowsFormsApp2.sln

The location a copy-paste: C:\Users\Salam\source\repos

Edit: When I start the VS 2019 then I choose "continue without code". After that, from the menu, I click on File -> New -> File... I get the same error message "Ilegal characters in path". Or simply when I click from the keyboard "ctrl+n" I get the same error message.

Comment: Can you show the regional settings of your PC (Language Settings)?

Comment: Region is Germany. Language is English USA

Comment: [Another victim](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1278838/illegal-characters-in-path-3.html).  The stack trace they supplied is useful, I'm 90% sure that this is caused by a corrupted PATH environment variable.  Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables to fix.

Comment: Some how, from the windows, there is either " is added to your paths or / chars

Comment: did you try to use CLI to generate the projects? donet commands?

Comment: Agree with @Hans Passant , check it please, and let us know the result

Comment: I have checked that also, but I didn't find any quotation marks. I will try to add a snapshot of it

Comment: Actually, I didn't use the CLI to generate the project since I am not used to doing that. I am gonna try it.

Comment: Please copy that `Location` (from the VS UI) and paste it into your question. **Make sure you paste it**. I suspect there is a hidden space in their somewhere.

Comment: Why are some of your paths `c:\users` and some `d:\users`?

Comment: I was able to generate a new project and a new class using CLI without facing any problem.

Comment: Yes, I usually create projects in two different directories. D:\Users\Salam\source\repos\ and C:\Users\Salam\source\repos\. The VS itself is on D drive. But could this cause this  problem?

Comment: Sorry, which location pleas? What do you mean by UI?

Comment: `Sorry, which location pleas? ` https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIrFq.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225950/discussion-between-salam-hanna-and-mjwills).

Answer (score 4):

You probably have an invalid system path (**NOT** user path, which you have shown at your last image), as I just got this bug and found a fix for it.

Apparently my system path had a path called <path to add>; https://i.stack.imgur.com/727q5.png.
This is an invalid path, you can check for all paths by doing echo $env:path in PowerShell and then find a path that's invalid.
Now you need to delete the invalid path. I don't know how to do it without downloading another software, but I used [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/download) (launch with admin privileges or it'll only be read only) to delete.

Restart VS2019 and it should work

Comment: This was exactly it for me. The latest update had combined the two existing path variables into one, and then re-added both of them. Deleting the combined path variable fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; it turned out that there was an invalid path present in my userpath, namely `E:source/bin`. However, there was no such folder on my E drive.

Look for any incorrect paths that may exist in the userpath.