# When trying to create a new 'Standalone TypeScript Angular Project' in VS 2022 I get an Error Message "Visual Studio Code: Illegal characters in path"

Tags: angular, visual-studio

When trying to create a new 'Standalone TypeScript Angular Project' named HealthCheck in VS 2022 I get an Error Message "Visual Studio Code: Illegal characters in path" when I click the create button to run the project for the first time. It will not create a project with all the necessary files, just a HealthCheck Folder with a HealthCheck.sln file which I cannot run. Thank you in advance and please let me know if you need any clarifying information.

Things to note:

-I am locating the new project in a blank folder.

-My Environment Variable PATH includes C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs

-I repaired VS Community and reinstalled all components Node, Angular etc...

-I reset my computer

-I reinstalled all the packages for all the components involved.

-VS 2022 will let me successfully create a project with any of the other templates

-I reset all VS 2022 Import and Export settings to default

My Versions:
VS Template: Standalone TypeScript Angular Project
Project Name: Health Check
Location: C:\Projects
VS Community: 17.5.3
Angular CLI: 15.2.4
Node: 18.15.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
OS: win32 x64 Windows 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here.

[Visual Studio 2019 Illegal characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281107/visual-studio-2019-illegal-characters-in-path)

https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/vyzj95/illegal_characters_in_path_error/